# Is it possible to access another partition from recovery partition using command line?

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, custom-roms

Here's a situation: I've got Meizu 5 pro flashed with Flyme 6 which I flashed using TWRP recovery. I made few tweaks of the partitions (deleting and recreating and renaming) and then I wiped data.

Now the phone boots but as soon as it hits main interface I get error saying "internal storage is running out the process has been stopped" then it reboots and starts over, hits the message, reboots, starts over .... stays in this loop.

I still have access to:

- Meizu's recovery mode (which is kinda useless if I can't access root directory)
- locked fastboot mode (also little bit useless if it's locked)
- recovery partition through USB

I also have MRT dongle for repairing Chinese phones but it doesn't seem to work unless the phone boots fully into Android.

What I can do about this ? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I'm with you, but to flash TWRP onto the phone I need unlocked bootloader. My bootloader is locked hence I'm trying to think of a workaround.

Comment: When I run `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img` I get "Permission denied".

Comment: What flashing does ? It just extracts all files from an image or zip file. Correct ? Sorry this is the first time I'm playing around with internals of Android.

Comment: @alecxs  I wasn't locked before. It got locked when I flashed it with Flyme 6.

Comment: If you want you can take a look here for more info:  https://forum.xda-developers.com/meizu-pro-5/help/meizu-reboots-internal-storage-running-t4074897

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to get my phone to use TWRP, from which I can flash Flyme 5, unlock it and then I can flash the phone with custom ROM.

Comment: @alecxs SP Flash Tool requires a scatter file that supposedly comes with ROM, I've got a few ROMs here and none includes a scatter file hence I can't use the tool.

Comment: I reworded my post.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. The partition will show up as a root directory in command line interface. The same goes when trying to browse the partition with Python.